# Google map search interfering with mySQL

Tags: google-maps, search, street-address

I'm having an issue displaying markers from my database while allowing the user to search their address (search is an autocomplete). I can either display the markers or complete a search, however I'd like to do both.

From all the testing I've done, I'm thinking there may be some conflict with my JavaScripts? Not entirely sure though. Could you guys have a look? Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance, code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/auto.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-autocomplete.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.866584707354, 151.2188931196655),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="address" size="60"><br/><br/>

<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    load(); 
});

$(function(){
              $('#map').gmap3();

      $('#address').autocomplete({
        source: function() {
          $("#map").gmap3({
            action:'getAddress',
            address: $(this).val(),
            callback:function(results){
              if (!results) return;
              $('#address').autocomplete(
                'display', 
                results,
                false
              );
            }
          });
        },
        cb:{
          cast: function(item){
            return item.formatted_address;
          },
          select: function(item) {
            $("#map").gmap3(
              {action:'', name:'marker'},
              {action:'addMarker',
              latLng:item.geometry.location,
                map:{center:true, zoom:8}
              }
            );
          }
        }
      })
      .focus();
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```